# meaning of some commands ? , the hackers play book 2

Tags: command-line, man, documentation

i don't understand what's the meaning of the -a in dpkg --configure -a and what's the meaning of the -y is apt -y install ? , i always find-letters that i never understand what's there meaning , can any one share with me a link of a dictionary that explain them that would be great .
also if any of you read the hacker playbook 2 i could use some constant help pls , i  have so many questions about it .
thanks for your help.

Comment: Use `man dpkg` to know about dpkg options. Use `man apt` to know about apt options.

Comment: I googled the hacker playbook and do not see at present directly how it relates to your question

Answer (score 2):

Virtually all commands, especially those designed for command-line use, have a manual page. For a command `cmd` this is displayed in a command shell by typing `man cmd`. There you can read about all command line switches and their parameters. You find the official manual pages online at [die.net](https://linux.die.net/man/) or at [man7.org](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/) and at various other sites.

Moreover, most commands can be queried for a brief usage description by `cmd -?`, those that require parameters often display it when typing `cmd`, some commands give a more verbose description on `cmd --help` (sometimes `cmd -help` or `cmd -h`).